# Chrome 37 - BGR subpixel text rendering

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, rendering, cleartype

I am lucky to have a screen with BGR subpixel layout.

With lucky I mean that Google Chrome 37 now forced RGB subpixel rendering with their recently added DirectWrite text rendering method. Text is exhausting to read now.

Does anyone know how to force a BGR subpixel layout?

Comment: Did you run the ClearType optimizer thingy yet? It’s supposed to support BGR, although I don’t know if affects DirectWrite.

Comment: It changes the system settings, yeah. But Chrome completely ignores this when initializing DirectWrite, which is unchained with the system settings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For now, there are two workarounds, but no real possibility to set the subpixel rendering to BGR.

Go to `chrome://flags` and set the flags stated below to the specified values.

1. **Disable DirectWrite completely and use the old GDI drawing methods.**
   You can completely disable the new rendering method and use the old one as in pre-36.
   `Disable DirectWrite`: set it to *Enable*
2. **Use grayscale subpixel rendering instead of red and blue**
   Keep using DirectWrite, but subpixeling will not use red and blue, but grayscale colors instead.
   `LCD text antialiasing`: set it to *Disabled*

Restart Chrome and you will see the changes.

EDIT: A recent comment around my bug reports says it will be fixed in the upcoming Chrome versions.

Comment: Thanks so much for the workaround!  I wish Chrome updates would come with a heads-up notification for situations like this: "This is why your fonts may suddenly look strange, and how to revert the change if needed..."

Comment: Well I'd be happy if they'd just respect BGR subpixel rendering. This is a bug if you ask me. Adobe Reader does the same error.